# pass an item id to from card to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-modal

so i have a 3 cards that has its value taken from database
i want to get the id of the particular card that was clicked and send it to modal so i can echo it in the modal

i tried sending it to the button trigger as data-id=< ?php $card_id ?> but that doesn't seem to work

```
php & mysql codes to fetch from database  

<div class="container">
<div class="title">
    <h5><?php echo $card_id; ?></h5> <h1><?php echo $card_title; ?></h1>
    <div class="body">
        <?php echo $card_name; ?>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="button" data></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h1><?php echo $card_id; ?></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using Ajax for this.

Keep **`data-id="<?php echo $card_id; ?>"`** in your button.

Create a php page to process the ID to be echoed:

```
if ($_POST['cardid']) {
     $id = $_POST['cardid'];
     echo $id;
}
```

Use a modal event to push the ID to your modal's body using a class declaration:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
          var cardid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
          $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url: 'record.php',
               data: 'cardid='+ cardid,
               success: function(data){
                    $('.fetched-data').html(data);
               }
          });
     });
});
```

Put the class declaration in your modal body where you want the ID to show:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1 class="fetched-data"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```